# Cannot install PEAR on Centos 6.5 and PHP 5.5

Tags: centos, php, pear, glibc

This is driving me nuts already and there's no information about this whatsoever in Google, only 2006 posts, but they don't really help me.

I have CentOS 6.5 freshly updated, PHP 5.5, MySQL, Apache, NodeJS and some other web dev stuff, not really dirty local environment.

I even removed completely all pear files:

> rm -rf 'find / -type f -name  "pear*"'

Then, I installed the fresh version:

> wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
>
> php go-pear.phar

And I always get this:

> http://pastebin.com/nbpkKatG

Please help guys....

> /tmp/glibctestXXXX issue?

I have all glibc packages already:

```
[root@localhost pear]# rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
glibc-static-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
glibc-utils-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I personally would have used the `php-pear-*` packages provided by EPEL (with the `php-pear` package coming from CentOS itself), I don't really see the problem. The installer script says the `pear` executable was installed - is it working as expected or not? If not, please post that error. I tend to disergard error messages about temporary files in `/tmp` - perhaps a bad practice but it's never yet bitten me on the butt.

Comment: Yeah, i've rolled back to php-pear, but it throws the same errors. I'm checking right now if the package installation went well anyway.

Comment: Yeah looks ok. It's just xdebug were yelling too much on a poorly written PERL code :)